# Docker writes data not only in volume

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04, docker-volume

Here is my setup:

- 4 Services: Worker, Database (Postgis), Rest-API and a Mapserver
- 1 Volume for the Database

```
docker volume inspect pgdata
[
   {
       "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
       "Driver": "local-persist",
       "Labels": {},
       "Mountpoint": "/mnt/pgdata",
       "Name": "pgdata",
       "Options": {
           "mountpoint": "/mnt/pgdata"
       },
       "Scope": "local"
   }
]
```

2 disks/partitions:

```
 df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs            13G  856K   13G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       939G   10G  889G   2% /
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
s3fs             16E     0   16E   0% /codede
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1        46T   24K   44T   1% /mnt/pgdata
```

As you can see the partition mounted at /mnt/pgdata has 44TB storage and I want all the data stored in the Database to be stored there as it will get huge really fast.

But when I start to add data to the database, the 1TB disk will get filled subsequently and my system will fail/stop.

```
  database:
    image: DB_IMAGE
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    command: postgres -c 'max_connections=500'
    ports:
      - "6543:5432"
    secrets:
      - postgres-user
      - postgres-password
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER_FILE: /run/configs/postgres-user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/postgres-password
      POSTGRES_DB: ts
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
```

The workers are running on the nodes, mapserver and Rest-API are expected to have really small influence on the harddisk.
So the only service running affecting the storage should be the database.

Why would it still fill the smaller diskspace instead of only the big one?

EDIT:
Apparently my container still takes a huuuuge amount of space on the disk. The container is the ts_database container.
[image]

EDIT2:
So i found out why it is that big: logging. My ID-json.log file takes up the 630GB, after checking the docs https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/ I hope I can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you describe volume inside `docker-compose.yml`?

It is [should be described](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose) even if already created externally:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

# service description
services:
  frontend:
    image: node:lts
    volumes:
      - myapp:/home/node/app

# volume description
volumes:
  myapp:
    external: true
```

Or

```yaml
volumes:
  pgdata:
    external: true
```

In your case

### UPDATE ANSWER ACCORDING INFORMATION IN COMMENTS:

> So apparently inside my /var/lib/docker-directory there is a subfolder with 125GB of disk space usage

`/var/lib/docker/volumes` is a default path for docker volumes.

Looks like your container using different `pgdata` volume. Maybe you not correctly described it (see my answer above). Here is hard to guess what happened according provided information.

If volume is really correctly described and still don't working I may recommend two workarounds:

1. Use direct mount without volumes:

   ```yaml
   volumes:
     - /mnt/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
   ```
2. Mount second drive to `/var/lib/docker` to store all docker data at big disk by default:

   ```sh
   # stop docker
   service docker stop
   # unmount current folder
   umount /mnt/pgdata
   # rename old docker folder
   mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker_old
   # create new folder
   mkdir /var/lib/docker
   # mount
   mount /dev/sdb1 /var/lib/docker
   # copy docker files to new position
   cp -pr /var/lib/docker_old/* /var/lib/docker/
   # check for hidden files starting from `.` if exists and copy it too
   ls -la /var/lib/docker_old/
   # remove old folder
   rm -fr /var/lib/docker_old
   # mount /dev/sdb1 to /var/lib/docker as permanent storage using /etc/fstab file
   # start docoker and enjoy
   service docker start
   ```

Comment: Yes I did, sorry I left this part out.

Comment: @Felix hmm, maybe you mounted second disk after mounting docker? Is `/mnt/pgdata` empty? try to un-mount it and check `/mnt/pgdata` again. Also [check what directories](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-largest-file-in-directory-recursively-using-find-du/) actually docker using to store data.

Comment: Yes I mounted the disk after installing docker. So I have to reinstall docker to use it?

Comment: I didn't say anything about installing. Check /mnt/pgdata with mounted disk and without. Which folder is empty? Or it empty in both ways?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. Right now it is mounted and used as a volume. There is data associated to postgres in the directory. Thats fine for me, there is some data getting there. But at the same time there is much more data getting stored on the other disk? Guess I have to find out where this data is stored actually

Comment: So apparently inside my /var/lib/docker-directory there is a subfolder with 125GB of disk space usage (du -h returned it). The subfolder is linked to the database container. Would it be helpful to install docker on the new, big disk instead and use another subfolder as pgdata?

Comment: Thanks for the Update. I will try your 2nd approach and update you if it worked as I intended it to do :D

Comment: If I use the 2nd possibility, without a volume (?) my data would be lsot if the container is removed/stopped working right?

Comment: `If I use the 2nd possibility, without a volume (?) my data would be lost` → both workarounds allows to keep data. In both ways you have to transfer data from old to new place manually. Mounted data is storing at disk permanently even if container removed

Comment: Ok thats perfect. Thanks for the help. I used the 2nd approach, declared a new volume and added it in the compose-file to the database service.

Comment: I added an image with screenshot to my question as my problem seems to still stand.

Comment: I actually forgot to save the edit. The image is now in the question. Any idea why this container still takes that much space?